# what does it mean typedef char *b?

Tags: c++11, pointers, memory-management, operator-keyword

I'm reading through this memory management code overloading operator new.  there's expression something like

```
typedef char *b
```

and later in the code b was used like this:

```
b(h); //h is a pointer to some class;
```

h defined here:

```
static Head* h= (Head*) HEAP_BASE_ADDRESS;
```

I'm assuming when b is used it is considered a pointer to a char.  But how can a pointer have expressions like b()??  Is there some sort of conversion going on in here?  Can I understand it as b now is having the same address as h?

Comment: `b` is defined to be a type name, specifically an alias for `char*` type. `b(h)` is a function-style type cast, equivalent to `((char*)h)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code line you posted is a [`typedef`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) which creates an alias for `char*` as `b`. The second code line shows a *functional-style* [type conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) from `h` to `b`.

> Can I understand it as b now is having the same address as h?

The `b` is just an alias of `char*`, so `b(h)` eventually does nothing unless you store the result of that expresion like:

```
b b_ptr = b(h); // equivalent to: char* b_ptr = ((char*)h);
```

The functional-style type conversion works only with *single-word type names*, so if you want to use this conversion style to e.g. a pointer, you have to `typedef` it first. (This is the reason of the `typedef char *b`.) This style of conversion can be used for expressions like `int(3.14 + 6.67)`.

Comment: thanks alot. Now I get it.  The origin code was used like this:  return (void*) (b(h) + sizeof(Head)); So it basically returns back the address of 1 head size away from this character address.  Everything's clear now.  Much appreciated

Comment: The original code you commented here (`return (void*) (b(h) + sizeof(Head));`) is a strange way saying `return (void*)(++h);` but I don't see the complete code.